How to assign anonymous VLA to pointer?
Currently I am assigning a VLA to a pointer as follows
struct Foo {
    int* array;
};

int array[size];

struct Foo foo = {
    .array = array;
};

Is it possible to replace this with an "anonymous" array?
What I tried:
struct Foo foo = {
    .array = (int[size]) {} // fatal error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
};

What I was hoping for:
struct Foo foo = {
    .array = int[size]; // something similar to this if I am making any sense.
};

PS: I am not looking for dynamic memory allocation (malloc/calloc).

Are some of these declarations supposed to be inside a function?  Because variably modified types cannot be used at file scope, so even your named array version requires a function context.

@GrandeKnight Instead of trying to use a VLA you can allocate an array dynamically as for example struct Foo foo = {
.array = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) ) };

@JohnBollinger I am using it in main function. Does that count?

@GrandeKnight, yes, main() is a function.

@VladfromMoscow  I want the array to be in the stack. I edited my question to clarify.

You are probably looking for a compound literal.  In that case, you could use a VLA, but you would be better off not.

@JohnBollinger From the C23 Standard: "2 The type name shall specify a complete object type or an array of unknown size, but not a variable
length array type.
"

@JohnBollinger Compiler shows error for VLA in compound literal.

Not necessarily a good solution either, but have you considered alloca?

Re "I want the array to be in the stack", You could use alloca/_alloca.

@ikegami Oh i just looked up alloca. Isn't VLA feature supposed to remove alloca?

Apparently not in structs.

@alagner So this is a dead end then. Seems like I have to stick to it for now.

@GrandeKnight, What does "remove alloca" mean? Remove for the C standard? It was never in it. Remove the need for it? Apparently not.

@ikegami I meant remove it's usage since it is not standard.

@GrandeKnight if the only thing that about an array init in some function, then set it with memset() instead of {} like int array[size]; memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

Beware of using alloca() in loops...

I take that back. Re "Isn't VLA feature supposed to remove alloca?", You could use a VLA. You've showed this. It's trying to use an anonymous VLA that's giving you a problem.

@yvs2014 But I have to declare the array in the end anyway.

@yvs2014, Using int array[size]; .array = array already works without the memset. The OP is trying to avoid doing int array[size];.

@ikegami Yeah, seems like there is no alternative yet.

@GrandeKnight struct Foo { int* array; }; int main() { int size = 100; int array[size]; memset(array, 0, sizeof(array)); struct Foo foo = { .array = array }; .. }

@ikegami I don't think so: int main() { int size = 100; int array[size] = {}; ..  leads to that fatal error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Is there a reason size must be a variable and not a compile-time constant?

@yvs2014 It seems you are missing the whole point of this post. I want to remove int array[size]; from the code.

@yvs2014, Remove the = {} you added to the OP's working code.

@Lundin yeah, size will be user input.

@ikegami {} is in the origin and can be replaced with memset()

And dynamic allocation won't work because...?

@yvs2014, Please read the question again. It says that this works: int array[size]; struct Foo foo = { .array = array; }; The question is how to make the array anonymous.

@Lundin sticking to stack as array will be small

@ikegami fatal error: variable-sized object may not be initialized caused by initialization, no idea what you're trying to say

@yvs2014 .array = (int[size]) {} is causing the error. .array = array works fine.

C23 will allow it. CLANG already supports it. See https://godbolt.org/z/55a191sGq


Is it possible to replace this with an "anonymous" array?

No.
Specifically, you are asking how to create an anonymous variable-length array. C does not support those.
Of compound literals ((){}), the C standard says:

C17 §6.5.2.5 ¶1 The type name shall specify a complete object type or an array of unknown size, but not a variable length array type.

Your only options are the nonstandard alloca/_alloca.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/78374624/23116730, the latest clang using c23 std compiles the code without errors but I keep getting segfaults. If it is just buggy then that suits as the answer better. So I have accepted neither answer for now.

C23 isn't out yet. The latest draft still contains the exact language I quoted ("C23[N3096] §6.5.2.5 ¶1 The type name shall specify a complete object type or an array of unknown size, but not a variable length array type.") So despite what the other answer says, (int[size]) {} isn't valid C23 as it currently stands.


Is it possible to replace this with an "anonymous" array?

No, not if the wanted size cannot be given in the form of an integer constant expression, unless you're willing to use an allocation function.
Of objects recognized by C language semantics, only literals, dynamically allocated objects, and certain structure and union members are without any name anywhere.  Compound literals of VLA type are expressly forbidden (they violate a language constraint).  Structures and unions cannot have members of VLA type, so you can't get one through a compound literal of such a type, either.  The "certain structure and union members" I referred to are for completeness only; they have structure or union type themselves, so they are no help.  You have ruled out dynamic memory allocation, so there's nothing left.
If there is an upper bound on the size you want to support (and in practice there is, because stack space is pretty limited) then you could use an array of that size instead.

Given the "must be allocated on the stack and array must be small", one obvious solution would be this:
struct Foo {
    int array [MAX];
    size_t size;
};

That is, always allocate some 256 bytes but keep track of how much of that is used to store data.
As a bonus, you get rid of one level of indirection by placing the array directly in the struct which might give an itty bit of performance increase.
